# AJAX Post sometimes works, sometimes it doesnt, why?

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, ajax, laravel

I have several ajax posts in my pages and i find that somedays they do work correctly:

- executes the method in the controller.
- doesnt refresh page.

Sometimes it doesnt:

- executes the method in the controller.
- goes to a blank page.

I dont find a relation of when they work or they dont, it seems random but i hope its not.
I searched several stack overflow posts and articles and still couldnt find the reason hence why i am making this questin. Hope you understand that.

**An example of an Ajax call that sometime works and sometimes not:**

```
$(document).ready(function() {

        $('form.ajaxaccount').on('submit', function(event) {
            event.preventDefault();

            $.ajaxSetup({
                headers: {
                    'X-CSRF-TOKEN': $('meta[name="csrf-token"]').attr('content')
                }
            });

            $.ajax({
                method: 'POST',
                url: '/saveaccount', // This is the url we gave in the route
                data: $('form.ajaxaccount').serialize(),
                success: function(response){ // What to do if we succeed
                    var stack_bar_bottom = {"dir1": "up", "dir2": "right", "spacing1": 0, "spacing2": 0};
                    new PNotify ({
                        title: "Sucesso",
                        text: "Editado com sucesso! ",
                        styling: "bootstrap3",
                        addclass: "stack-bottomright custom",
                        nonblock: {
                            nonblock: true
                        },
                        stack: stack_bar_bottom
                    });  
                },
                error: function(jqXHR, textStatus, errorThrown) { // What to do if we fail
                    var stack_bar_bottom = {"dir1": "up", "dir2": "right", "spacing1": 0, "spacing2": 0};
                    new PNotify ({
                        title: "Erro :(",
                        text: "Os dados inseridos não foram guardados. Tenta novamente",
                        styling: "bootstrap3",
                        addclass: "stack-bottomright custom",
                        nonblock: {
                            nonblock: true
                        },
                        stack: stack_bar_bottom
                    });  
                }
            });
        });
    });
```

**FULL PAGE:**

```
    <!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">

<head>
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
    <meta name="csrf-token" content="{{ csrf_token() }}">
    <title>Wolistic</title>
    <link href="./css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet">
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="http://code.jquery.com/ui/1.12.1/themes/base/jquery-ui.css">
    <link href="./css/style.css" rel="stylesheet">
    <link href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Open+Sans:300,400,600,700" rel="stylesheet">
    <script src="https://use.fontawesome.com/a3f24bf03b.js"></script>
    <link href="dist/notyf.min.css" rel="stylesheet">
    <script src="dist/notyf.min.js"></script>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="{{ asset('vendor/backpack/pnotify/pnotify.custom.min.css') }}">
</head>

<body>
    @include('frontoffice.login_popup')
    @include('frontoffice.register_popup')
    <header>
        <div class="top_bar_right">
            <div class="container">
                <ul>
                @if (Auth::guard('web_customer')->guest())
                        <!--Seller Login and registration Links -->
                        <li><a id="openloginpopup"> Iniciar Sessão </a></li>
                        <li><a id="openregisterpopup"> Registar </a></li>

                    <ul class="lang_switch">
                        <li>Pt</li>
                        <li><img src="./img/down_arrow.png" width="9"></li>
                    </ul>
                @else
                    <li class="dropdown">
                        <a href="#" class="dropdown-toggle" data-toggle="dropdown" role="button" aria-expanded="false">
                            {{ Auth::guard('web_customer')->user()->name }} <span class="caret"></span>
                        </a>

                        <ul class="dropdown-menu" role="menu">
                            <li>
                                <a href="{{ url('/customer_logout') }}"
                                    onclick="event.preventDefault();
                                            document.getElementById('logout-form').submit();">
                                    Logout
                                </a>

                                <form id="logout-form" action="{{ url('/customer_logout') }}" method="POST" style="display: none;">
                                    {{ csrf_field() }}
                                </form>
                            </li>
                        </ul>
                    </li>
                @endif
                </ul>
            </div>
        </div>
        <nav id="mainNav" class="navbar navbar-default">
            <div class="container">

                <div class="navbar-header">
                    <button type="button" class="navbar-toggle collapsed" data-toggle="collapse" data-target="#navbar-collapse-1">
                    <span class="sr-only">Toggle navigation</span> Menu <i class="fa fa-bars"></i>
                </button>
                    <a class="navbar-brand page-scroll" href="{{ url('/eventos') }}">
                        <img src="img/wolistic_logo.png" class="logo" alt="Wolistic" title="Wolistic" />
                    </a>
                </div>

                <div class="collapse navbar-collapse" id="navbar-collapse-1" class="menu">
                    <ul class="nav navbar-nav navbar-right">
                        <li>
                            <a class="page-scroll" href="#download">Sobre Nós</a>
                        </li>
                        <li>
                            <a class="page-scroll" href="#features">Workshops</a>
                        </li>
                        <li>
                            <a class="page-scroll" href="#contact">Eventos</a>
                        </li>
                        <li>
                            <a class="page-scroll" href="#contact">Voluntariado</a>
                        </li>
                        <li>
                            <a class="page-scroll" href="#contact">Submeter Evento</a>
                        </li>
                    </ul>
                </div>
            </div>
        </nav>
        <form class="col-md-12 search_form">
            <div class="container">
                <input type="text" name="search_term" class="search_term" id="search_term" placeholder="O que procuras? (Ex. Permacultura)" />
                <select name="event_type" id="event_type" class="event_type" placeholder="Tipo">
                    <option value="" disabled selected hidden>Tipo</option>
                    <option>Evento</option>
                    <option>Workshop</option>
                    <option>Voluntariado</option>
                </select>
                <select name="event_local" id="event_local" class="event_local" placeholder="Tipo">
                    <option value="" disabled selected hidden>Local</option>
                    <option>Porto</option>
                    <option>Braga</option>
                    <option>Lisboa</option>
                </select>
                <input type="text" name="event_begin_date" class="event_begin_date" id="event_begin_date" placeholder="Data (início)" />
                <input type="text" name="event_end_date" class="event_end_date" id="event_end_date" placeholder="Data (fim)" />
                <button id="submit" class="search_submit"></button>
            </div>
        </form>
    </header>
    <main>
        <div class="container">
            <div class="breadcrumb">
                <span>Início</span> > <span>Perfil</span>
            </div>
            <div class="profile_title">
                A MINHA CONTA
            </div>

            <div class="row">
                <div class="left_sidebar col-md-3 left_aboutus">
                    <img 
                        @if (is_null($customer->profile_pic)) 
                            src="\uploads\{{ $customer->profile_pic }}"
                        @else
                            src="./img/default_profile_picture.png"
                        @endif
                        class="img-responsive profile_pic" />
                    <h1 class="profile_name"> {{ $customer->name }} </h1>

                    <div class="perfil-menu text-left">
                        <div class="perfil-accordion">
                            <div class="panel-group" id="accordion">
                                <div class="panel panel-default notbordered">
                                    <div class="panel-heading active">
                                        <h4 class="panel-title" >
                                            <a class="accordion-perfil-tog-link-main" href="{{ url('/account') }}">Eu sou</a>
                                        </h4>
                                    </div>
                                </div>
                                <div class="panel panel-default notbordered">
                                    <div class="panel-heading">
                                        <h4 class="panel-title">
                                            <a data-toggle="collapse" data-parent="#accordion" href="#1collapse2" aria-expanded="false" class="collapsed">Eu gosto<span class="accordion-perfil-tog-link accordion-perfil-tog-plus"><i class="fa fa-angle-down" aria-hidden="true"></i></span></a>
                                        </h4>
                                    </div>
                                    <div id="1collapse2" class="panel-collapse collapse" aria-expanded="false" style="height: 0px;">
                                        <div class="panel-body">
                                            <ul>
                                                <li><a href="{{ url('/customerinteresses') }}" class="">Os meu interesses</a></li>
                                                <li><a href="{{ url('/wishlist') }}" class="">Wishlist</a></li>
                                            </ul>
                                        </div>
                                    </div>
                                </div>
                                <div class="panel panel-default">
                                    <div class="panel-heading ">
                                        <h4 class="panel-title">
                                            <a data-toggle="collapse" data-parent="#accordion" href="#1collapse3" class="collapsed" aria-expanded="false">Eu quero<span class="accordion-perfil-tog-link accordion-perfil-tog-plus"><i class="fa fa-angle-down" aria-hidden="true"></i></span></a>
                                        </h4>
                                    </div>
                                    <div id="1collapse3" class="panel-collapse collapse" aria-expanded="false" style="height: 0px;">
                                        <div class="panel-body">
                                            <ul>
                                                <li><a href="{{ url('/newsletter') }}" class="">Newsletter</a></li>
                                                <li><a href="{{ url('/password_reset') }}" class="">Alterar password</a></li>
                                                <li><a href="{{ url('/accountdelete') }}" class="">Apagar conta</a></li>
                                            </ul>
                                        </div>
                                    </div>
                                </div>
                            </div>
                        </div>
                    </div>

                    <!--
                    <div class="button_anunciante">EU SOU ANUNCIANTE</div>
                    -->

                    <div class="perfil-menu-anunciante text-left">
                        <div class="perfil-accordion">
                            <div class="panel-group" id="accordion">
                                <div class="panel panel-default ">
                                    <div class="panel-heading ">
                                        <h4 class="panel-title">
                                            <a class="accordion-perfil-tog-link-main" href="{{ url('/advertiser') }}">Eu sou anunciante</a>
                                        </h4>
                                    </div>
                                </div>
                                <div id="anunciante-options" class="">
                                    <div class="panel panel-default ">
                                        <div class="panel-heading ">
                                            <h4 class="panel-title">
                                                <a data-toggle="collapse" data-parent="#accordion" href="#2collapse2" aria-expanded="false" class="collapsed">Os meus eventos<span class="accordion-perfil-tog-link accordion-perfil-tog-plus"><i class="fa fa-angle-down" aria-hidden="true"></i></span></a>
                                            </h4>
                                        </div>
                                        <div id="2collapse2" class="panel-collapse collapse" aria-expanded="false" style="height: 0px;">
                                            <div class="panel-body">
                                                <ul>
                                                    <li><a href="{{ url('/myevents') }}" class=""> Os meus eventos </a></li>
                                                    <li><a href="{{ url('/addnewevent') }}" class=""> Submeter evento </a></li>
                                                </ul>
                                            </div>
                                        </div>
                                    </div>
                                </div>
                            </div>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                </div>
                <div class="page_content col-md-6 col-md-offset-1">

                    <div class="separator"></div>

                    <h3 class="personal_data">DADOS PESSOAIS</h3>
                    <div class="separator_personal"></div>
                    {{ Form::open(array('method'=>'post','class'=> 'profile_form ajaxaccount', 'url'=>'/saveaccount')) }}
                            <div class="form-group">
                                <label for="exampleInputEmail1"> Nome </label>
                                <input type="text" name="name" class="form-control" value="{{ $customer->name }}" placeholder="{{ $customer->name }} ">
                            </div>
                            <div class="form-group">
                                <label for="exampleInputEmail1"> Email </label>
                                <input type="email" name="email" class="form-control" value="{{ $customer->email }}" placeholder="{{ $customer->email }}"> 
                            </div>
                            <div class="form-group">
                                <label for="exampleInputEmail1"> Telemóvel </label>
                                <input type="text" name="phone" class="form-control" data-country="PT" value="{{ $customer->phone }}" placeholder="{{ $customer->phone }} ">
                            </div>
                            <div class="form-group">
                                <label for="exampleSelect1">Distrito / região </label>
                                <select class="form-control" name="districtID" id="exampleSelect1">
                                        @foreach ($districts as $district)
                                            <option value="{{ $district->id }}" > {{ $district->name }} </option>
                                        @endforeach
                                        </select>
                            </div>
                            <button type="submit" class="btn btn-primary">GUARDAR DADOS</button>
                    {{Form::close()}}
            </div>
        </div>
        </div>
        <div class="separator"></div>
        <div class="separator"></div>
        <div class="separator"></div>
        <div class="separator"></div>
    </main>

    @include('frontoffice.footer')

    <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.12.4/jquery.min.js "></script>
    <script src="https://code.jquery.com/ui/1.12.1/jquery-ui.js "></script>
    <script src="./js/bootstrap.min.js "></script>
    <script src="./js/script.js "></script>
    <script src="vendor/backpack/pnotify/pnotify.custom.min.js"></script>
    <script>
        $(document).ready(function() {

            $('form.ajaxaccount').on('submit', function(event) {
                event.preventDefault();

                $.ajaxSetup({
                    headers: {
                        'X-CSRF-TOKEN': $('meta[name="csrf-token"]').attr('content')
                    }
                });

                $.ajax({
                    method: 'POST',
                    url: '/saveaccount', // This is the url we gave in the route
                    data: $('form.ajaxaccount').serialize(),
                    success: function(response){ // What to do if we succeed
                        var stack_bar_bottom = {"dir1": "up", "dir2": "right", "spacing1": 0, "spacing2": 0};
                        new PNotify ({
                            title: "Sucesso",
                            text: "Editado com sucesso! ",
                            styling: "bootstrap3",
                            addclass: "stack-bottomright custom",
                            nonblock: {
                                nonblock: true
                            },
                            stack: stack_bar_bottom
                        });  
                    },
                    error: function(jqXHR, textStatus, errorThrown) { // What to do if we fail
                        var stack_bar_bottom = {"dir1": "up", "dir2": "right", "spacing1": 0, "spacing2": 0};
                        new PNotify ({
                            title: "Erro :(",
                            text: "Os dados inseridos não foram guardados. Tenta novamente",
                            styling: "bootstrap3",
                            addclass: "stack-bottomright custom",
                            nonblock: {
                                nonblock: true
                            },
                            stack: stack_bar_bottom
                        });  
                    }
                });
            });
        });
    </script>
</body>
</html>
```

**FORM from the above page:**

```
{{ Form::open(array('method'=>'post','class'=> 'profile_form ajaxaccount', 'url'=>'/saveaccount')) }}
                        <div class="form-group">
                            <label for="exampleInputEmail1"> Nome </label>
                            <input type="text" name="name" class="form-control" value="{{ $customer->name }}" placeholder="{{ $customer->name }} ">
                        </div>
                        <div class="form-group">
                            <label for="exampleInputEmail1"> Email </label>
                            <input type="email" name="email" class="form-control" value="{{ $customer->email }}" placeholder="{{ $customer->email }}"> 
                        </div>
                        <div class="form-group">
                            <label for="exampleInputEmail1"> Telemóvel </label>
                            <input type="text" name="phone" class="form-control" data-country="PT" value="{{ $customer->phone }}" placeholder="{{ $customer->phone }} ">
                        </div>
                        <div class="form-group">
                            <label for="exampleSelect1">Distrito / região </label>
                            <select class="form-control" name="districtID" id="exampleSelect1">
                                    @foreach ($districts as $district)
                                        <option value="{{ $district->id }}" > {{ $district->name }} </option>
                                    @endforeach
                                    </select>
                        </div>
                        <button type="submit" class="btn btn-primary">GUARDAR DADOS</button>
                {{Form::close()}}
```

What could be wrong ?

Comment: It can sometimes be hard figuring out how to ask for help, but could you please take a look at [How to ask a good question?](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask)

Comment: `it seems random but i hope its not` - I can almost guarantee it's not. Code is never going to do something you don't tell it to do, code can't be wrong, but it can be programmed to give you the wrong results by mistake

Comment: Intermittent issues like this generally point to server and/or hosting issues, such as bandwidth/request throttling. I'd suggest you check the response when the request fails, and also talk to your hosting company.

Comment: Did you check for errors in the console? Press <F12> to get the programmer tools (windows, chrome, IE and Firefox).

Comment: So if the form submits, sounds like you have an error in your JS and the code is not being executed.... But in the end all we can do is guess why....

Comment: Code is never random. Computers don't make mistakes, only programmers do. However, this question is impossible to answer without a [Minimal, Complete and Verifiable Example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve). The only advice I can give you, is to check the console for errors or warnings.

Comment: Checked the logs? Laravel.log, nginx.log, apache.log...?

Comment: No errors on console and its always submited, the code is executed it just ends on a blank page. Im getting desesperated to get this working. :(~

Comment: About the only thing that could easily be "random' in your example code might be an issue with the CSRF token if your page is never supposed to refresh. Try setting your URI to be excluded (https://laravel.com/docs/5.4/csrf#csrf-excluding-uris) - if that solves the issue you know that is your culprit.